# Combining two setvalue strings

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to adapt my inEdit script to give not just a timestamp but also add a "2" in another field,

I thought the following would work but only the date works and it ignores my "2".

What am I missing for both the date and 2 to appear onEdit?

```
function onEdit() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  if( s.getName() == "Sanshiro" ) { //checks that we're on the correct sheet
    var r = s.getActiveCell();
    if( r.getColumn() == 6 ) { //checks the column
      var nextCell = r.offset(0, -5);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue(new Date());
        nextCell = r.offset(0, 10);
      if( nextCell.getValue() === '' ) //is empty?
        nextCell.setValue("2");
    }    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if the check if the 'nextcell' is empty is really needed ? you still want to update that cell if a new edit takes place, right ? Anyway, I think you can simplify your script to:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (e.source.getActiveSheet()
    .getName() !== "Sanshiro" || e.range.columnStart !== 6) return //checks that we're on the correct sheet
e.range.offset(0, -5)
    .setValue(new Date());
e.range.offset(0, 10)
    .setValue(2);
}
```

Comment: Hi JPV, thanks as always for your support. 

I get the error 
"TypeError: Cannot read property "source" from undefined. (line 2, file "Code")"

Using the code you provided. I don't quite understand.

Also I do need the is empty clause as I don't want the onEdit to overwrite.

Comment: @Rattle: did you try to run the code from the script editor ? That would explain the error. The script uses a simple trigger and is 'triggered' by EDITS taking place in the spreadsheet. If you are in the script editor, no edits take place, hence no 'event object' is passed in all parameters to e will be undefined. Simply go to the spreadsheet 'Sanshiro' and edit col 6 and see what happens.

Comment: Ah right.. Again sorry for my severe lack of knowledge..
I thought you have to run the script in order for it to work. 

I tried the script you kindly provided but still the "2" doesn't appear in column 11 or any for that matter. 

Also how would I implement the 'is empty' line with your script?

Comment: Tested it and seems ok. Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet ?

Comment: Hi JVP, 
Thanks here's the latest revision of my sheet. Has changed quite a bit since you last saw it I think. 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6mDHrXdbvzJwnODPtBEafyBp2tux56NZRHAfB-S9_E/edit#gid=872357380

Comment: Also do you know what line I would need to trigger an edit on any cell in a row?
I.e. not just edits on col 6 but on any column. (Want to make a 'last edited' date field)

Comment: The sheet is not accessible. Can you fix that ? So you want the script to be triggered by edits in any column ?

Comment: So sorry!! 
Here's the public version:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6mDHrXdbvzJwnODPtBEafyBp2tux56NZRHAfB-S9_E/edit?usp=sharing

I was hoping for a version as above, but also I want to make another script to refresh a date each time the row is edited.

Comment: I still don't have editing rights, so I can't access the script editor in order to change the script..

Comment: Crap I'm really sorry. busy day today. 

This one's editable
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I6mDHrXdbvzJwnODPtBEafyBp2tux56NZRHAfB-S9_E/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I changed the script so that it now is triggered by edits in any column (expect for columns 1 and 16). See if that works ?

Comment: Ok I'm sorry if I'm not very clear. 

I've made some adjustments.

It wasn't working so well when I have it looking for edits on all columns.(it would reenter the date and 2 even when deleting those fields)

Anyway, I've reverted it back, but I'd like the col1 date to update when 'Update' is selected on the drop down. 
This along with the existing function of 
onedit of col6 
adding new date in col10

Comment: Changed the script so that it now stamps the last col, when 'update' is selected in col 1 and it writes 2 when col 6 is edited. See if that helps ?

Comment: Hmm I really appreciate your help so far but I'm afraid that's a little different to what I need..

I need the 'if empty' line to stop exisiting date being overwritten.
Also If 'updated' is selected in the drop down, I want that text to be overwritten with the date..

My previous script was so close but I was having trouble getting all three actions to work together..

Comment: If you want col 1 to update with the new date (after selecting update) does that mean you want a new datestamp every time you select update ? Made some changes.. see how we are doing now..

Comment: Wow great. Very close now. If I then along with adding the 2, I want to add the date in the Col15 (O)?

Your scripts seem super efficient but I certain do have more problem understanding them so it's hard to adjust them myself :(

Comment: Col15 again with an 'if-empty' check ?

Comment: Also I need that script to work with all the named tabs, i.e. Sanshiro, Yujiro, Josh, Suil, Martin..

Comment: All the tabs or just the ones you named in previous comment ?

Comment: Just the ones I mentioned. 

Yes needed an if empty check for the Col15 too..


Thank you!!

Comment: Okay.. Can you test again ?

Comment: JPV, thank you so much. Finally I have managed to achieve what I needed all thanks for you help. 

You've also helped me learn so much and I just wanted to let you know how grateful I am. 

Thanks again.